# Python typehints for a generic interface / c++ template equivalent

Tags: python, templates, interface, typing

I want to have a generic typehinted interface in python.
What I want to reach is roughly the following, but I'm stuck finding a solution:

```
T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')


class GenericInterface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, number: T)->S:
        pass


def get_example()->GenericInterface[int, str]:

    class Example(GenericInterface[int, str]):
        def get(self, number: int)->str:
            return str(number)

    return Example()
```

So in the above example `GenericInterface[int, str]` should describe the following typed interface:

```
class MyInterface(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, number: int)->str:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generic) is what you're looking for:

```py
class GenericInterface(Generic[T, S], ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self, number: T) -> S:
        pass
```

Admittedly, I'm not sure if `Generic` or `ABC` needs to confirm first, but you get the point.